# Unable to update data in array of objects using redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux-toolkit

I have defined an empty array using redux toolkit in **createSlice()** to store file's data. I am pushing an object whenever user clicks on create file...

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Untitled",
    content: "",
    date: "20/03/2022",
    time: "03:23 PM",
  },
]
```

Now I want to update content whenever user open the file, type something and save it but unable to do it once file is created...

I can only read the data. I need a way to update the content.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using Reacts State Management via `useContext()` and `useReducer()` Hook instead of Redux.

With Redux you have to deal with prop drilling, meaning a lot of extra code just to get the application started. By using Context to nest components within components, all the functionality from the parent component is available in the child components.

It is also easier, more intuitive and without any additional dependency since it is available since React v16.8

Below you will see what each step looks like in React:

**useContext() Hook:**

```
const newContext = React.createContext({ color: "blue" });

const value = useContext(newContext);

console.log(value); // this will log { color: "black" }
```

**useReducer() Hook:**

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer((state, action) => {
  const { type, payload } = action;
  switch(action) {
    case "ADD_FILE":
      return [
        ...state,
        payload
      ];
    default:
      return state;
  }
}, []);
```

```
...
return (
  <button onClick={() =>
    dispatch({ type: "ADD_FILE", payload: YOUR_FILE_OBJECT})}>
  </button>
)
```

I would suggest pasting this in one `store.js` file:

```
import React, {createContext, useReducer} from 'react';

const initialState = [];
const store = createContext(initialState);
const { Provider } = store;

const StateProvider = ( { children } ) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer((state, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
      case "ADD_FILE":
        return [
          ...state,
          action.payload
        ];
      default:
        return state;
    };
  }, initialState);

  return <Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>{children}</Provider>;
};

export { store, StateProvider }
```

And using that in your `index.js`:

```
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import App from './App';
import { StateProvider } from './store.js';

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StateProvider>
    <App />
  </StateProvider>
);
```

Now you can edit the state in any child component like that:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { store } from './store.js';

const ExampleComponent = () => {
  const globalState = useContext(store);
  const { dispatch } = globalState;

  dispatch({ type: "ADD_FILE", payload: {
      id: 1,
      name: "Untitled",
      content: "",
      date: "20/03/2022",
      time: "03:23 PM"
    }
  })
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. but there's one more problem since I am building a notes app in react-native, the content can be huge. So I want to know will it be okay to store whole content as a string in object or there's any other way to store it like URLs.

Comment: Having large content in React state is perfectly fine. There is no general store limit.
The issue with large states appears if you start rendering them. If it is thousands of chars long it will slow down the browser, however a few hundreds shouldn't be a problem at all.